# Transform a class to an XML with its XSD inlined in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Using C#, I can easily serialize a class instance to an XML:

```
XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parking));
using (StringWriter sww = new StringWriter())
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true }))
{
    xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, myParking);
    var xml = sww.ToString();
    File.WriteAllText("myParking.xml", xml);
}
```

I can also create an XSD file for this class, using XSD.exe.
It is indeed possible to inline an XSD in an XML file (ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759142(v=vs.85).aspx)

**How can I get, in C#, my instance as an XML *having its XSD definition inlined* in it?**